# VIF - Muticollinearity - while using interaction terms in 'lm' method

Tags: r, lm

I am currently running a linear model with interaction terms, all variables are continuous.

lm (y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2)

While I am running the VIF, I am getting very high VIF (>50). However without interaction terms, the VIF is very low (<5).

Hence my question is; Is the VIF really matters when we run lm with interaction terms, and all variables (y and x) are continous?

Thanks in advance for the advise,

Comment: Thanks, the issue here is why multicollinearty is very high when interaction terms are introduced in 'lm', when all variables are continuous?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 1):

In short YES! The VIF does matters a lot - it will decrease the stability of your parameter estimates drastically and therefore decrease the ability to predict y in new data.

On way to reduce your problem might be to center x1 & x2 before the analysis (and there before you create the interaction term)

Comment: Thanks, the issue here is why multicollinearty is very high when interaction terms are introduced in 'lm', when all variables are continuous?

Comment: I dont't realy get your point. When you create an interaction term it has necesserily a substantial correlation with the variables you used for composing the interaction term.  The VIF is a global indicator for Multicollinearity - when you add a variable that is highly correlated with all your other predictors, it must get very worse!